# Unable to add Access TempVars variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am simply trying to create two variables in `TempVars`. Here is the relevant code:

```
Private Sub cboFilterFavorites_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo ApplyFilterFavorites_Err

    If (IsNull(Me.cboFilterFavorites) Or Me.cboFilterFavorites = 0) Then
        ClearFilter
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (Me.cboFilterFavorites = -1) Then
        ManageFilters
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Apply Filters
    TempVars.Add "FilterString", DLookup("[FilterString]", "T_Filter", "ID = " & Me.cboFilterFavorites)
    TempVars.Add "SortString", DLookup("[SortString]", "T_Filter", "ID = " & Me.cboFilterFavorites)

    With Me.Form
        If (Not IsNull(TempVars!FilterString)) Then
            .Filter = TempVars!FilterString
            If Not .FilterOn Then
                .FilterOn = True
            End If
        End If
    
        If (Not IsNull(TempVars!SortString)) Then
            .OrderBy = Nz(TempVars!SortString)
            If Not .OrderByOn Then
                .OrderByOn = Not IsNull(TempVars!SortString)
            End If
        End If
    End With

    TempVars.Remove "FilterString"
    TempVars.Remove "SortString"

ApplyFilterFavorites_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ApplyFilterFavorites_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ApplyFilterFavorites_Exit

End Sub

Public Function ManageFilters() 'Opens the filter form.

    On Error GoTo ManageFilters_Err

    TempVars.Add "ObjectType", Application.CurrentObjectType
    Debug.Print TempVars!ObjectType
    TempVars.Add "ObjectName", Application.CurrentObjectName
    Debug.Print TempVars!ObjectName
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFilter", acNormal, "", "[ObjectName]=[TempVars]![ObjectName]", , acDialog
    Me.Refresh
    TempVars.Remove "ObjectType"
    TempVars.Remove "ObjectName"

ManageFilters_Exit:
    Exit Function

ManageFilters_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ManageFilters_Exit

End Function
```

The weird thing is if I put a stop at the beginning of the event and step through the code it works. But if I run it as normal it does not (meaning `[TempVars]![ObjectType]` = -1; `[TempVars]![ObjectName]` = blank)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tempvars.add) is what Microsoft says on the method. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's working as designed, but no object is selected while running this code, these are the values it should return if no object is selected. Can you please provide a [mre]? Which values do you expect?

Comment: @ErikA Not sure what you mean by `no object is selected`. It's called from a combobox event. Maybe that's why? But can you explain further? It was working in a previous form but when I transfered it to a new form it puts `-1`. I expect `2` because it's a form, and the form name.